# Why don't quantile regression curves (qgam / mgcv) fit the probabilities optimally?

Tags: r, probability, mgcv, quantile-regression

I'd like to model the optimal quantile regression curves of probabilities as function of xa, using qgam ideally (mgcv-based R package), but not necessarily:

**Data:**

```
dat <-
structure(list(prob = c(0.043824528975438, 0.0743831343145038, 
0.0444802301649798, 0.0184204002808217, 0.012747152819121, 0.109320069103749, 
0.868637913750677, 0.389605665620339, 0.846536935687218, 0.104932383728924, 
0.000796924809569913, 0.844673988202945, 0.00120791067227541, 
0.91751061807481, 0.0140582427585067, 0.61360854266884, 0.55603090737844, 
0.0121424615930165, 0.000392412410090414, 0.00731972612592678, 
0.450730636411052, 0.0111896050578429, 0.0552971757296455, 0.949825608148576, 
0.00216318997302124, 0.620876890784462, 0.00434032271743834, 
0.809464444601336, 0.890796570916792, 0.0070834616944228, 0.0563350845256127, 
0.913156468748195, 0.00605085671490011, 0.00585882020388307, 
0.0139577135093548, 0.0151356267602558, 0.00357231467872644, 
0.000268107682417655, 0.047883018897558, 0.137688264298974, 0.846219411361109, 
0.455395192661041, 0.440089914302649, 0.312776912863294, 0.721283899836456, 
0.945808616162847, 0.160122538485323, 0.274966581834218, 0.223500907500226, 
0.957169102670141, 3.29173412975754e-05, 0.920710197397359, 0.752055893010363, 
0.204573327883464, 0.824869881489217, 0.0336636091577387, 0.834235793851965, 
0.00377210373002217, 0.611370672834389, 0.876156793482752, 0.04563653558985, 
0.742493995255321, 0.42035122692417, 0.916359628728296, 0.182755925347698, 
0.139504394672643, 0.415836463269909, 0.0143112277191436, 0.00611022961831899, 
0.794529254262237, 0.000295836911230635, 0.88504245090271, 0.0320097205131667, 
0.386424550101868, 0.724747784339428, 0.0374198694261709, 0.772894216412908, 
0.243626917726206, 0.884082536765856, 0.649357153222083, 0.651665475576256, 
0.248153637183556, 0.621116026311962, 0.254679380328883, 0.815492354289526, 
0.00384382735772974, 0.00098493832845314, 0.0289740210412282, 
0.919537164719931, 0.029914235716672, 0.791051705450356, 0.535062926433525, 
0.930153425256182, 0.739648381556949, 0.962078822556967, 0.717404075711021, 
0.00426200695619151, 0.0688025266083751, 0.30592683399928, 0.76857384388609, 
0.817428136470741, 0.0101583095649087, 0.190150584186769, 0.949353043876038, 
0.000942385744019884, 0.00752842476126574, 0.451811230189468, 
0.878142444707428, 0.085390660867941, 0.705492062082986, 0.00776625091631656, 
0.120499683875168, 0.871558791341612, 0.204175216963286, 0.88865934672351, 
0.735067195665991, 0.111767657566763, 0.0718305257427526, 0.001998068594943, 
0.726375812318976, 0.628064249939129, 0.0163105011142307, 0.585565544471761, 
0.225632568540361, 0.914834452659588, 0.755043268549628, 0.44993311080756, 
0.876058522964169, 0.876909380258345, 0.935545943209396, 0.856566304797687, 
0.891579321327903, 0.67586664661773, 0.305274362445618, 0.0416387565225755, 
0.244843991055886, 0.651782914419153, 0.615583040148267, 0.0164959661557421, 
0.545479687527543, 0.0254178939123714, 0.00480000384583597, 0.0256296636591875, 
0.776444262284288, 0.00686736233661002, 0.738267311816833, 0.00284628668554737, 
0.0240371572079387, 0.00549270830047392, 0.91880163437759, 0.336534358175717, 
0.276841848679916, 0.718008645244615, 0.0897424253787563, 0.0719730540202573, 
0.00215797941000608, 0.0219160132143199, 0.797680147185277, 0.66612383359622, 
0.946965411044528, 0.133399527090937, 0.343056247984854, 0.202570454449074, 
0.00349712323805031, 0.919979740593237, 0.577123238372546, 0.759418264563034, 
0.904569159000302, 0.0179587619909363, 0.785657258439329, 0.235867625712547, 
0.959688292861383, 0.668060191654474, 0.0014774986557077, 0.00831528722028647, 
0.669655207261098, 0.157824457113222, 0.110637023939517, 0.262525772704882, 
0.112654002253028, 0.22606090266161, 0.157513622503487, 0.25688454756606, 
0.00201570863346944, 0.70318409224183, 0.25568985167711, 0.810637054896326, 
0.92708070974999, 0.608664352336801, 0.707490903842404, 0.00094520948858089, 
0.106177223644193, 0.582785205597368, 0.0585327568963445, 0.377814739935042, 
0.972447647118833, 0.0111118791692372, 0.58947840090326, 0.0111189166236961, 
0.00317374095338712, 0.0664218007312096, 0.00227258301798719, 
0.00198861129291917, 0.337443337988163, 0.750708293355867, 0.837530172974158, 
0.627428065068903, 0.744110974625108, 0.00320417425932798, 0.871800026765784, 
0.613647987816266, 0.808457030433619, 0.00486495461698562, 0.597950577021363, 
0.000885253981642748, 0.0800527366346806, 0.00951706823839207, 
0.125222576598629, 0.346018567766834, 0.0376933970313487, 0.157903106929268, 
0.0371982251307384, 0.00407175432189843, 0.0946588147179984, 
0.967274516618573, 0.169109953293894, 0.00124072042059317, 0.00259042255361196, 
0.000400511359506596, 0.841289470209085, 0.807106898740506, 0.926962245924993, 
0.814160745645036, 0.662558468801531, 0.000288068688170646, 0.698932091902567, 
0.00242011818508616, 0.645573844423654, 0.517121859568318, 0.0931231998319089, 
0.000877774529895907), xa = c(6.85, 7.65, 7.6, 6.65, 7.35, 8.6, 
9.8, 8.25, 9.65, 7.6, 5.95, 11.75, 6.05, 10.75, 7, 8.25, 7.25, 
7.55, 6.4, 7.45, 7.15, 7.1, 7.4, 8.85, 6.65, 7.75, 6.95, 7.25, 
9.35, 6, 7.5, 9, 7.1, 7.75, 7.55, 6.95, 6.85, 5.8, 7.4, 7.45, 
9.7, 8.1, 7.6, 8.1, 8.45, 9.45, 8, 7.25, 7.05, 9.5, 5.05, 10.15, 
8.7, 7.7, 8.4, 7.5, 9.25, 6.85, 7.45, 11.85, 7.9, 7.6, 8.3, 10.35, 
7.95, 7.9, 8.65, 7.05, 6.9, 9.6, 5.5, 12.2, 7.45, 7.5, 7.2, 7.05, 
8.7, 7.25, 8.35, 8.45, 8.05, 8.05, 8.25, 7.7, 9, 6.95, 6.75, 
6.55, 8.9, 7.4, 9.35, 8.45, 10.35, 8.65, 9.6, 8.75, 7.05, 7.8, 
7.95, 8.4, 8.3, 7.6, 8.3, 8.7, 6.65, 7.1, 7.7, 10.1, 7.75, 9.05, 
6.5, 6.3, 9.45, 7.7, 7.65, 8.15, 7.35, 7.6, 7.2, 8.35, 7.65, 
6.8, 11.45, 7.35, 12.65, 9.15, 8.15, 10.6, 8.6, 11, 9.85, 9.2, 
9, 7.8, 7.25, 7.65, 8.35, 8.4, 7.55, 7.55, 7.55, 6.95, 8.15, 
8.65, 6.95, 8.5, 4.75, 7.3, 7.65, 9.15, 7.45, 8.2, 7.8, 7.3, 
7.35, 6.1, 7.35, 7.25, 8.15, 9.55, 7.15, 7.15, 7.2, 7.2, 8.25, 
8.7, 8.85, 10.35, 7.5, 7.45, 7.05, 15.15, 8.7, 6.15, 6.55, 16.05, 
7.6, 6.55, 7.45, 7.6, 8.15, 6.05, 6.55, 6.65, 7.35, 7.3, 9.4, 
10.05, 10.85, 8.5, 6.4, 7.15, 7.5, 6.25, 7, 9.55, 6.85, 8.2, 
6.7, 7.2, 7.25, 7.05, 7.25, 6.9, 9.1, 9.4, 7.45, 7.8, 5.55, 7.8, 
8.7, 7.65, 6.9, 8.25, 6.4, 7.5, 7.55, 7.95, 7.35, 7, 7.3, 6.65, 
6.65, 6.9, 8.65, 8.25, 5.95, 6.55, 6.1, 7.7, 10.95, 11.15, 8.85, 
7.35, 6, 7.75, 5.45, 7.55, 7.1, 7.35, 6.45)), row.names = c(NA, 
-241L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code:**

```
library(qgam)
library(mgcViz)
library(ggplot2)
 
# qgam
qg.5 <- qgamV(prob ~ s(xa, bs="tp", k=20), data = dat, qu = 0.5)
qg.25 <- qgamV(prob ~ s(xa, bs="tp", k=20), data = dat, qu = 0.25)
qg.75 <- qgamV(prob ~ s(xa, bs="tp", k=20), data = dat, qu = 0.75)

# add fitted values to dat
dat$fit_prob.5 <- qg.5[["fitted.values"]]
dat$fit_prob.25 <- qg.25[["fitted.values"]]
dat$fit_prob.75 <- qg.75[["fitted.values"]]

# predict xa at prob = 0.5
xa_at_prob.5 <- with(dat, approx(fit_prob.5, xa, xout=0.5)); xa_at_prob.5

# plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x = xa, y = prob)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit_prob.5), lwd = 1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit_prob.25), lwd = 1.2, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit_prob.75), lwd = 1.2, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = xa_at_prob.5[["y"]], linetype = "longdash", color = "black", linewidth = 0.6) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16, 1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(0, 0.5, 1), linetype="solid", color = "black", linewidth = 0.3) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(4, 13))
```

However, looking at the graph below, I've two concerns:

**Question 1:** Some fit_prob.25 values are negative, as shown on the 0.25 quantile curve (blue area 1).
I think this is because qgam does not consider prob values as probabilities, i.e., values that must be constrained between 0 and 1.
Is it the problem? How to solve it?

**Question 2:** Surprisingly, the curves don't seem to fit the data very well; there are more points in red zone 2 (about n=30) than in zone 3 (about n=10). Slightly more left and steeper quantile curves would seem to fit better (like the approximative red median curve part). Is there an explanation for this inappropriate fitting?

[image]

Any help, advice or reference would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It looks to me like your model has left out an important factor; judging (possibly incorrectly!) from the points between `xa=7` and `xa=8`, there are a lot with very low probabilities *and* a lot with probabilities > 0.5.  `xa` is not doing a good job of distinguishing between them, unlike for lower and higher values.   This, I suspect, is the root of the quantile regression problem.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps the limits of the quantile regression are exceeded in such a situation. I've also tried several GAM-based regressions, varying k and/or the basis function, but it's no better. Maybe a specific family would be required, while making varying other arguments, which I do not know well unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `gam` with beta regression (family="[betar](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/Beta.html)") is more appropriate for modeling probabilities and it pretty much answers both questions. Adjusting theta=50 and k=15 gives the best fitting.

```
library(mgcViz)
library(qgam)
library(ggplot2)
 
# qgam and gam
qg.5 <- qgamV(prob ~ s(xa, bs="cr", k=15), data = dat, qu = 0.5); summary(qg.5)
btr <- gamV(prob ~ s(xa, bs="cr", k=15), data = dat, method = "REML", family = betar(link = "logit", theta = 50)); summary(btr)
gam.check(btr)
# add fitted values to dat
dat$fit_qg.5 <- qg.5[["fitted.values"]]
pred <- predict(btr, newdata = dat, se.fit = TRUE, type="response")
dat$fit_btr <- pred[["fit"]]
dat$se.fit_btr <- pred[["se.fit"]]
dat$low <- dat$fit_btr - 2 * dat$se.fit_btr
dat$upr <- dat$fit_btr + 2 * dat$se.fit_btr

# predict xa at prob = 0.5
xa_at_prob.5 <- with(dat, approx(fit_btr, xa, xout=0.5)); xa_at_prob.5

# plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x = xa, y = prob)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit_qg.5), lwd = 1.2, color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit_btr), lwd = 1.2, color = " red") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = xa, ymin = low, ymax = upr), alpha = 0.3, fill = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = xa_at_prob.5[["y"]], linetype = "longdash", color = "black", linewidth = 0.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16, 1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(0, 0.5, 1), linetype="solid", color = "black", linewidth = 0.3) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(4, 13))
```

Note: The deviance explained cannot be compared between qgam and gam. The number of basis dimension (k) is quite acceptable:

```
Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

      k' edf k-index p-value
s(xa) 14  12       1    0.52
```

[image]

**Edit:**

As relevantly explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qgam/vignettes/qgam.html) by Matteo Fasiolo (more details [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.03303.pdf)), "*since the variance of prob varies with xa, the bias induced by the smoothed pinball loss used by `qgam` is not constant. This issue can be solved by letting the learning rate change with xa*". In this way, the following code almost completely answers question 1, while increasing the qgam deviance explained from 65% to 94%:

```
# qgam with list(...bs="ad")
qg.5_ad <- qgamV(list(prob ~ s(xa, bs="ad", k=20), ~ s(xa)), data = dat, qu = 0.5); summary(qg.5_ad)
qg.25_ad <- qgamV(list(prob ~ s(xa, bs="ad", k=20), ~ s(xa)), data = dat, qu = 0.25)
qg.75_ad <- qgamV(list(prob ~ s(xa, bs="ad", k=20), ~ s(xa)), data = dat, qu = 0.75)
```

providing the blue quantile regression curves below. However, it does not answer question 2 (goodness of fit), which would perhaps require to create a discontinuity starting at the pink area, but which is certainly not possible using smooth effects.

[image]